# unexpected token = for class properties in node 8.4

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-class, class-fields

running the following code in node (v8.4)

```
class TodoStore {
    todos = [];

    get completedTodosCount() {
        return this.todos.filter(
            todo => todo.completed === true
        ).length;
    }

    report() {
        if (this.todos.length === 0)
            return "<none>";
        return `Next todo: "${this.todos[0].task}". ` +
            `Progress: ${this.completedTodosCount}/${this.todos.length}`;
    }

    addTodo(task) {
        this.todos.push({
            task: task,
            completed: false,
            assignee: null
        });
    }
}

const todoStore = new TodoStore();

todoStore.addTodo("read MobX tutorial");
console.log(todoStore.report());

todoStore.addTodo("try MobX");
console.log(todoStore.report());

todoStore.todos[0].completed = true;
console.log(todoStore.report());

todoStore.todos[1].task = "try MobX in own project";
console.log(todoStore.report());

todoStore.todos[0].task = "grok MobX tutorial";
console.log(todoStore.report());
```

gives me the following error:

```
        todos = [];
              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:537:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:609:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:598:3
```

Comment: ES6 does not support class properties.

Comment: see https://mobx.js.org/getting-started.html -> why is it allowed on the client side?

Comment: That's handled by a Babel plugin. https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/

Comment: which transpiles ES6...

Comment: No; which transpiles an as-yet-unreleased version.

Comment: @EladKatz it's at stage 2. Google how the TC 39 acceptance process works.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Update**
Support for instance class fields starts with **node >= 12**.

---

Literal class properties are not supported by any version of node, according to [this table](https://node.green/#ESNEXT-candidate--stage-3--instance-class-fields). You'll still have to set any instance properties inside your class constructor:

```
class TodoStore {

    constructor() {
        this.todos = [];
    }
    // ...
}
```

If you wish to define a `static` property, you'd assign that directly to the `TodoStore` reference, after the class has been declared:

```
TodoStore.todos = [];
```

Comment: take a look here: https://mobx.js.org/getting-started.html - how come it's used there then? why is it ok on the client?

Comment: That code is most certainly being transpiled to standard ES5 JS code before it is run. The most commonly used tool for that is [BabelJS](https://babeljs.io/). There's nothing that would prevent you to do the same, but the code will for now simply not work in node natively, or any other widely adopted environment.

Comment: It's now available in the nightly Node v 12. +1 for linking the table to help make future-proof the answer, plus it's useful for other features as well.

Comment: At first this answer mislead me into believing it is not yet supported in ANY version of node. Answer should specify that any prior to version 12

Comment: It's there now.

Answer (score 3):

Instance class fields will be supported as of Node v12, so one solution is to use a version >= 12 once it is released.

https://node.green/#ESNEXT-candidate--stage-3--instance-class-fields

For now if you're interested the nightly builds are at: https://nodejs.org/download/nightly/